# Using Omnipay with Icepay

Tags: expressionengine, omnipay, webshop

Is there already a way available to use Omnipay with Icepay? I didn't see it anywhere in the third party list of Omnipay, but someone else might have already made something for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have an IcePay gateway built, but would happily take either A: a PR to add a third party package if you've built one, or B: a request that one be built in the near future.

If you want to build it yourself, I'm happy to help in anyway you can. Otherwise, I can open up on issue on the omnipay main repo and have i tagged for an upcoming version.

Comment: I see. I currently don't have time to make this myself, since our company is very busy with projects for customers, so I'm suggesting that you open up an issue about this indeed. It would be great if you could add Icepay to Omnipay soon. Icepay is very big, so I think that a lot of people would like Icepay to be in the Third Party list. Thanks!